# Plotting Vector data on Raster Map

Tags: qgis, cartography, geotiff-tiff, digital-image-processing

I have a Raster map with East,West, North and south boundaries as follows
(-118.875,-118.75,37.125,
37) and a Vector data. Now I want to plot a vector lines on this raster map. the vector line is in JSON format  : "geometries": [
    {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          -124.21855199991967,
          40.725894000326946
        ],
        [
          -124.21783999992073,
          40.72704999928351
        ],
        [
          -124.21660999992264,
          40.72901999928047
        ]
      ]
    },

To plot this line on the map, I was confused how to consider the E,W,N,S values. If I take line vector as (x1,y1), (x2,y2)..... and if I can conver E,W,N,S values to (x,Y) format, with this reference I can start plotting. I am coding in C# to achieve the above. How to consider the E,W,N,S values as (X,Y) ?

Is my approach is right if their are other efficient way please do share.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are already in x, y format. The north and south boundaries are y values and the east west boundaries are x values. If that is the actual line you are trying to plot, it is outside the boundaries of your raster.

Comment: Are the West boundary and South boundary can be considered as a origin  ?  and How can I convert this latitude and longitude values to index positions to locate a particular pixel in map [an array containing the pixel values of the amp]and to do seeding around the pixel at a particular point do we have any standard library in C# ?